# How to stop query results being duplicated in html options drop down box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Using parse.com and Javascript SDK.

UPDATE - I've created a fiddle to show the issue http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/j8vgqvqg/11/

The below code returns a list of friends the current user is connected to. It then displays the results in a options drop box for the user to select a friend. There are 3 records in parse with the status of "Connected", 3 records are shown in the inspect elements in Chrome too.

For some reason when the results are being displayed in the drop box they are being duplicated.

I need to include both toUser and fromUser, other wise only using one of these you only get 1/2 the friend connections.

How can I stop the duplication in the drop down box? A working example/anwser would be amazing!

```
 ![var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
         var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

        var queryOne = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
        queryOne.equalTo("toUser", currentUser);


        var queryTwo = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
        queryTwo.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);

        var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(queryOne, queryTwo);
        //mainQuery.include('toUser');
        mainQuery.include('fromUser');
        mainQuery.equalTo("status", "Connected");


            mainQuery.find({
            success: function(results) {
                var friends = \[\];
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    friends.push({
                        username: results\[i\].get('fromUser').get('username'),

                        userId: results\[i\].get('fromUser').id,



                    });
                    var select = document.getElementById("selectFriend");
                    $.each(friends, function(i, v) {
                        var opt = v.userId;
                        var optfrontend = v.username;

                        var el = document.createElement("option");
                        el.textContent = optfrontend;
                        el.value = opt;
                        select.appendChild(el);
                    })

                }
            },

            error: function(error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
         });
```

HTML

```
                <option value="0">Select a friend</option>
```

[image: 3 friend connections in parse]
[image: front end is showing duplicates of connection]
 [image: parse results show 3 records]

Comment: That seems to be a problem with your logic … you have two queries, one getting the `toUser` from the friend requests, and the other getting the `fromUser` … and then you put _both_ those queries into your main query. Only logical that you are getting duplicate results that way.

Comment: @CBroe I think I mentioned above, but I need to include both. A friend request can be fromUser or toUser if both are not used you only get 50% of the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [$.unique()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/) to remove duplicates from the array:

```
friends = $.unique( friends );
```

Untested, but could also work directly in the $.each:

```
$.each($.unique(friends), function(i, v) { ...
```

**Update:** As using $.unique() doesn't work for the `friends` array, possibly `friends` consists of unique entries having the same username, but different other values - then it would be possible to use following approach:

```
var added = {};
$.each(friends, function(i, v) {
    var opt = v.userId;
    var optfrontend = v.username;
    if(!added[optfrontend])
    {
      added[optfrontend]= true;

      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = optfrontend;
      el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
    }
});
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y0s5c9d6/)

This will only add a username to the options that haven't been added previously by checking if `added[optfrontend]` is true while processing the `$.each()`.

As a sidenote - as you're using jQuery you could also use

```
var select = $("#selectFriend");
```

instead of

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectFriend");
```

but then you would have to change

```
select.appendChild(el);
```

into

```
select.append(el);
```

**Update:** Suggested approach works when the `var added = {};` as used in this approach is declared in the global scope, so it's accessible inside the `each()`. If it's declared just above the `each()`, but inside another function in the OP code, it will be undefined inside the `each()`.

Comment: I'll try, do I use both the lines you suggested or is that two different approaches?

Comment: @Dano007  Only one of them. The first would be before the `$.each(friends)`, and I just mentioned the second approach using `unique()` directly in the `each()` as it would save a line.

Comment: @Dano007 Ok, I've just added a second approach in my updated answer.

Comment: many thanks, still seem to have the issue....can you access this fiddle? I've created it here using parse http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/j8vgqvqg/11/

Comment: @Dano007 Yes, and fixed it in updated http://jsfiddle.net/j8vgqvqg/12/  It was just necessary to move the `var added = {};` on top (it's now between `var queryTwo` and `var mainQuery`), now it's working. I've added some console log messages so it's easier to check what's going on in the `each()`.